# RDKit on Python - GetMolSize method can't be employed

Tags: python-3.x, boost-python, rdkit

I'm trying to customize molecule drawer available on **RDKit** using Python 3.10.
Various drawers are implemented in the `Chem.Draw` module, and specifically `MolDraw2D` is the Base Class from which more specific drawers inherit various methods. The base class cannot be initialized in python but the subclasses can be.
The `GetMolSize` method should be available from these but unfortunately it is not. Do you know why ? It would be really useful for me.
Link to [doc](https://rdkit.org/docs/source/rdkit.Chem.Draw.rdMolDraw2D.html):

I'm using RDKit version **2022.09.5** but I think this is not the real obstacle.
PS: I already know of alternative methods to trace the actual size of the final molecule draw, but for a variety of draws it may be computationally burdensome.

Edit: Yes, this method was implented on **2023.03.1** version.